# Disable page nesting / content sections in Hugo and publish all pages at top-level?

Tags: hugo

It's been 5 years since I've last used Hugo, so there is a lot I am forgetting and perhaps some things have changed as well.

I use Hugo to publish a static blog, and for some reason everything is being published under a "Post" section that you have to click into, at which point the page is title "#Posts". I do not recall this ever happening before.

[I tried](https://kodify.net/hugo/pages/disable-section-pages/) using `--disableKinds=section` to successfully stop "Post" from showing up on my main page, but the children pages disappeared as well. In addition to wanting my blog posts to show up on my main page, I want the URL structure to reflect this corrected organization; i.e., right now everything is showing up under `mywebsite.com/post/article-name-here` when it should just be `mywebsite.com/article-name-here`.]

Within my repository, my blog articles are in fact stored under `content/post/article-name-here`, but when I moved my articles into the `content` directory directly, Hugo failed to display them.

I feel like this should be a very easy fix, but I'm clearly not using the right search terms to describe what is going on.

Please let me know what other information I can provide as I am having a hard time articulating what is going on.

[image: Main Hugo page with incorrectly displayed "Posts" article that leads to my actual posts.]

[image: Articles I want to appear at my top-level URL.]

Answer (score 1):

### Setting the permalink

> right now everything is showing up under `mywebsite.com/post/article-name-here` when it should just be `mywebsite.com/article-name-here`

When you are using a config.yaml file, you can add this to it:

```
permalinks: 
  posts: /:filename
```

That will eliminate the `post/` from your URL. For `.toml` you have to slightly alter the formatting.

### The homepage solution

If you change line 8 in your [layouts/index file](https://github.com/kenmhaggerty/angels-ladder/blob/master/layouts/index.html) from:

```
{{ $paginator := .Paginate (where .Data.Pages "Type" "post") }}
```

into:

```
{{ $paginator := .Paginate (where .Site.RegularPages "Type" "post") }}
```

... you will get the expected result (a list of your posts on the homepage). I tested it.

Comment: The permalink solution worked for individual blog pages but not the overall site, i.e., all of my blog posts are still listed under `mywebsite.com/post/` rather than `mywebsite.com`, but the individual articles do show up as `mywebsite.com/article-name-here`.

However, changing the directory name from `post` to `posts` just made no blog posts appear at `mywebsite.com`.

Comment: Sorry... I was mistaken. I digged deeper and found your theme. The error is on line 8 of your index.html file in your layouts directory. I corrected it (see above). Now it works in the latest version of Hugo as expected (tested).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the temporary solution I worked out thanks to Mr. Hugo's answer above/below:

- Set the [permalink configuration](https://gohugo.io/content-management/urls/) in my config.toml file as Mr. Hugo noted.
- Set `url = "article-name-here"` inside every blog post's Markdown file.
- Publish using `hugo` via command line, take the index.html and index.xml files within the `publish/post` directory, and move them into the `publish` directory (i.e., overwrite the index.html and index.xml files already there).
- Manually retitle the content of the `h1` tag inside index.html from "#Posts" to "Recent Articles".

Hopefully I can figure out a better answer and update this Stack Overflow question once I do.